# is external file like config.yml is not compiled in binary golang?

Tags: go, build

is external file like `config.yml` is not compiled when execute `go build` ?, or any other method for `compiling` with external file ?. if any method to execute `go build` included external file, please share to me. thanks

Comment: No. If you want to embed stuff during compilation you have to be explicite by using package embed.

Comment: Read the documentation of the [`embed` package](https://pkg.go.dev/embed@go1.17.8). You may also want to read the [How to use //go:embed](https://blog.carlmjohnson.net/post/2021/how-to-use-go-embed/) tutorial.